# How to update a Milestone's description with GitHubs's GraphQL API v4?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to update a milestone's description through the GraphQL API.

While updating a milestone was possible through the v3 REST API by:

`PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo/milestones/:number`

I'm unable to find a mutation for this purpose on the v4 docs here: https://developer.github.com/v4/mutation/

Is this feature not available in the v4 api?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token >>Insert your token<<" 
     --data "{ \"title\": \"Milestone name\", \"state\": \"open\", \"description\": \"Write the new description\"}" 
     -X PATCH  https://api.github.com/repos/>>Github account name or group name<</>>name of project<</milestones/>>Id of the milestone<<
```

In the `>> <<` you need to insert your information

How to do a token https://microclimate.dev/creatingpat

Normaly Id is 1 ... not a high number

this works on Windows cmd

Comment: here a example how the link could be it got scuffed with backlash https://api.github.com/repos/User1/test/1

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But my question was about using GitHub's GraphQL API, not the REST API.